# R install_github: Error: Failed to install 'unknown package'

Tags: r, git, github

I'm new to GitHub and I'm stumped. I can't get `install_github` to work.

I followed the helpful instructions here to set up my account: https://kbroman.org/github_tutorial/pages/init.html. 
I have an account and a repo where I store some R ggplot settings: 
https://github.com/tgraybam/TorontoPlot.

OK. Now I'd like to install the settings file from my repo into an R project, thus: `devtools::install_github('tgraybam/TorontoPlot')`.

But executing the command returns an error:

```
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub: HTTP error
404. Not Found Did you spell the repo owner (`tgraybam`) and repo name (`TorontoPlot`) correctly? - If spelling is correct, check that you
have the required permissions to access the repo.
```

I have `devtools` installed. 
I am not spelling anything wrong. 
It is my own repo. 
I can clone it just fine:

`git clone https://github.com/tgraybam/TorontoPlot.git`

I can use `install_github` with different repos (this works fine: 
`install_github("kbroman/broman")`.)

I can authenticate. `ssh -T git@github.com` returns

```
Hi tgraybam! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Just like it is supposed to.

I've Googled up a storm and tried everything I can think of (multiple times in multiple orders).

I'm using a Mac. Here are my system and R details:

```
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin15.6.0                
system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          5.2                         
year           2018                        
month          12                          
day            20                          
svn rev        75870                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
nickname       Eggshell Igloo
```

Can anyone out there help? Huge thanks.

Comment: `install_github()` only works for R packages (what you have there isn't a package; it doesn't have, for example, a `DESCRIPTION` file). You could clone the repo and source the functions if you wanted, but `install_github()` wouldn't be the way to go about it. Alternatively, you could finish building out what you have as an R package (see, for example, https://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/)

Comment: Thanks, @duckmayr! That makes total sense. Your comment is the answer. On to learning more about writing my own packages...

Comment: Probably the same error as in this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60143295/http-404-error-when-installing-r-package-from-public-repo-on-github-using-devtoo

Answer (score -1):

I met the same problem, then I used `remotes::install_github()` and seted `Sys.setenv("R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS" = "true")` from an R session.

Ref:

https://github.com/r-lib/remotes

https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/issues/403

Comment: The OP is reporting an *error* already. Setting `R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS` will not change that. And the issue you cite does not mention 404 errors at all.