# HTTP 404 error when installing R package from public repo on Github using devtools

Tags: r, git, github, devtools

I'm trying to install an R package from a public Github:

```
devtools::install_github(repo='FrankD/EDISON',
                         ref='MultipleTimeSeries', 
                         subdir='Package/EDISON/')
```

> Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
>     HTTP error 404.
>     Not Found
>
> Did you spell the repo owner (`datarichard`) and repo name (`EDISON`) correctly?
>     - If spelling is correct, check that you have the required permissions to access the repo.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? The same command used to work 7 months ago so something changed. My devtools version is 2.2.1

I've tried forking it to my own repo to remove any hidden authorisation issues but I get the same error, e.g.:

```
devtools::install_github(repo='datarichard/EDISON',
                         ref='MultipleTimeSeries', 
                         subdir='Package/EDISON/')
```

Comment: Just looking at the github account for `datarichard`, the repo name appears to be `frankd/EDISON`

Comment: yep, that is the guy I forked it from. I get the same error when pointing to his original repo - which I didn't 7 months ago. (would it be clearer if I updated the question to refer to the original repo instead?)

Comment: Using `subdir = '/Package/EDISON'` gives a new error message. Are you able to build and install this package locally?

Comment: That is it! I had the damn forward slashes in the wrong place. the correct syntax is in your comment: `subdir = '/Package/EDISON'`. If you want to write this up as an answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a forward slash on your subdir, and the ending slash can be removed:

```
devtools::install_github(repo='datarichard/EDISON',
                         ref='MultipleTimeSeries', 
                         subdir='/Package/EDISON') # here
```

Comment: Just to be clear. If this was the bug, then the error message is terrible, right? Should we file this as a bug to R?