# GnuTLS Error -50: Cannot install packages from Github in Rstudio?

Tags: r, git, libcurl, devtools, gnutls

The following lines prompt an error (which differs from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59332234/3552975)):

```
library(devtools)
install_github("StatsWithR/statsr") # the same for any other open repos
```

The error is this:

> Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
> Error -50 setting GnuTLS cipher list starting with +VERS-TLS1.3

Then I wanted to work around the problem caused by `devtools`, so I tried [githubinstall](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/githubinstall/vignettes/githubinstall.html), but the error became this:

> Error in curl::curl_download(input, tmpFile, mode = "wb", quiet = !showProgress) :
> Error -50 setting GnuTLS cipher list starting with +VERS-TLS1.3

It seems obvious that the issue is caused by `GnuTLS` and I found a similar thread: [git/jenkins TLS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62414353/3552975), but I cannot find some hints there.

I also tried `install_url`, `install_local`, and `install_git`, but all failed.

Here is the information of the R I recently upgraded from 3.4.4(2018):

```
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          1.2                         
year           2021                        
month          11                          
day            01                          
svn rev        81115                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
nickname       Bird Hippie
```

I have been stuck with `devtools` and `install_github`. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1):

I installed the r-base and Rstudio using apt install in an existing container, and the default settings(the default r version is 3.4.4) caused the issues I met, then I purged the r environment and created a new one in a new Docker container following this blog: [Running RStudio Server with Docker](https://davetang.org/muse/2021/04/24/running-rstudio-server-with-docker/).

Comment: can you include the most relevant info in your post? (presumably just `docker run <container>` with a volume mount to persist user files) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: @ti7 Thanks for your correction. Is it OK now?